# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(2x^{-t} - 1)^{-1/t}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

For $t>0$, I try to find the limit

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(2x^{-t} - 1)^{-1/t}}{x}$.

We can not apply L'Hopital's rule, since we do not have '0/0' and I don't see how I can manipulate the function such that we get a better form. 
What I have now is:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(2x^{-t} - 1)^{-1/t}}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x(2x^{-t} - 1)^{1/t}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x(\frac{2}{x^t} - 1)^{1/t}}$

Comment: We do have $0/0$ since $2x^{-t}$ goes to $\infty$ and $\infty^{-\frac{1}{t}}$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Should be as $x\to 0^+.$

Comment: for $t>0$ we get $$2^{-1/t}$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{2}{x^t} - 1 = \frac{2-x^t}{x^t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: L'Hopital not needed. Just note

$$ \left (\dfrac{2}{x^t} - 1 \right )^{1/t} = \frac{2^{1/t}}{x}\left (1-\dfrac{x^t}{2}  \right)^{1/t}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{(2x^{-t}-1)^{-1/t}}x=\frac{(2x^{-t})^{-1/t}(1-\frac1{2x^{-t}})^{-1/t}}x=\frac{(2^{-1/t}x)(1-\frac{x^t}{2})^{-1/t}}x=2^{-1/t}\underbrace{(1-\frac{x^t}{2})^{-1/t}}_{\to 1}$

I just got $x$ out of the $-1/t$ power, nothing tricky, and after simplifying it is not an undefined form any more.